# Solving $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{xy+{y}^{2}}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

> Solve $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\dfrac{xy+{y}^{2}}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}.$$

I have tried to solve this question by assuming $y/x$ to be $v$, but I am stuck on the integral $$\int\frac{{v}^{2}+1}{{v}^{3}-1},$$ please help me with this integral or suggest a method to directly solve the differential equation.

Comment: You want to integrate a rational function. There are standard ways to do it. What did you try?

Comment: I tried to separate the v^2 and 1 in the numerator, I was able to solve the first part but how do I integrate 1/(v^3-1)?

Comment: Partial fractions?

Comment: This type of questions are asked in the JEE exams, where we are required to solve it under three minutes, the approach which I have tried is very lengthy

Comment: Ok, thank you, partial fraction does the job

Comment: Can you provide a shorter approach?

Comment: You can try to multiply both side by the denominators ($dx$ and the sum of squares) and integrate.

Comment: Can you solve and put it in the answer? I am not able to understand what you wrote in the comment

Comment: I already spent more than 3 minutes.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain you've made an algebra error here. The relevant integrand should be $(1+v^2)/[v^2(1-v)]$.

Comment: No, I have not done that @eyeballfrog

Comment: As Aryadeva's answer indicates, you have. Most likely you used $(xy + x^2)/(x^2+y^2)$ as the RHS by mistake, which is a pretty easy thing to overlook.

Comment: As a secondary question, is the problem OK with an implicit expression for the solution? There is no elementary function $y(x)$ or $x(y)$ that solves that equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After factoring, this becomes easier:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} =\dfrac{xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{y\left(1+\frac yx\right)}{x\left(1+\left(\frac yx\right)^2\right)}$$
Substitute $u=\frac yx$ so that $y=ux$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx}$, which implies
$$u+x\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{u(1+u)}{1+u^2}\implies \dfrac{du}{dx} =\dfrac{u^2(1-u)}{x(1+u^2)}\implies\frac{u^2+1}{u^2(1-u)}\,du=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
This new DE is separable, so
\begin{align*}\int\frac{u^2+1}{u^2(1-u)}\,du&=\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx\\
\int\left(\frac{2}{1-u}+\frac{1}{u}+\frac{1}{u^2}\right)\,du&=\int\frac{1}{x}\,dx\\
-2\ln|1-u|+\ln|u|-\frac{1}{u}&=\ln|x|+C_1\\
2\ln|1-u|+\frac{1}{u}+\ln|x|-\ln|u|&=C_2\\
2\ln\left|1-\frac yx\right|+\frac{x}{y}+\ln|x|-\ln\left|\frac yx\right|&=C_2
\end{align*}

As confirmation, here’s a [slope field with some numerical solutions](https://homepages.bluffton.edu/%7Enesterd/apps/slopefields.html?flags=1&dydx=(x*y+y%5E2)/(x%5E2+y%5E2)&x=-4,4,20&y=-3,3,15&method=rk4&h=0.01&pts0=%5B0,1%5D,%5B0,2%5D,%5B0,-1%5D,%5B0,-2%5D,%5B3.66369607146836,1.6653507758893944%5D):

[image]

which matches up nicely with [plots of the solution we found](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ipv1me9zpc):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\dfrac{xy+{y}^{2}}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}.$$
You made a mistake somewhere. Substitute $y=tx$ gives
$$t'x+t=\dfrac{t^2+t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\dfrac {(t^2+1)}{t^2(1-t)}dt=\dfrac {dx}{x}$$
The integral that you need to evaluate is:
$$I=\int \dfrac {(t^2+1)}{t^2(1-t)}dt$$
$$I=\int \dfrac {dt}{1-t}+\int \dfrac {dt}{t^2(1-t)}$$
The last integral can be evaluated by substitution.

Substitute $u=\dfrac 1 t$
$$I_2=-\int \dfrac {u}{u-1}du=-u+C-\int \dfrac {du}{u-1}$$

Comment: Hi @Mathomania where exactly ?

Comment: I see no mistakes but can you tell me where I am wrong ?

Comment: That's what I got, too.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes I guess Op has made a misake somewhere.

Comment: Better to partial fraction expand: $(t^2+1)/(t^2(1-t)) = 2/(1-t)+1/t+1/t^2$

Comment: Yes sure it's better to use fraction decomposition. It was funny to evakuate it by substitution. @eyeballfrog

Comment: Since $\dfrac{xy+{y}^{2}}{{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}}=\dfrac{X+1}{X^2+1}; y\ne0$ and $$\int\dfrac{X+1}{X^2+1}=\dfrac12\log|X^2+1|+\arctan (X)+C$$ Can you deduce something of this?

Comment: I don't understand the question @Piquito What is X ? is it $X=x/y$ ? But on the left side of the differential equation you also have that $X$.

Comment: @Aryadeva.- Yes with the change of variables. On the other hand I don't know if my suggestion is good, it was a problem for you. Cheers.

Comment: Yes you can use that change of variable but then $y'=\dfrac {X-xX'}{X^2} $ @Piquito

Comment: @Piquito the DE becomes: $$-\int \dfrac {X^2+1}{X^2-X}dX=\int \dfrac {dx}{x}$$